# how to convert thunk action into a saga action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have the following action that logs in a user, using redux-thunk.

```
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
    Axios.post('/users/login', userData)
        .then( res => {
            // retrieve token from the response 
            const token = res.data.token;
            // console.log(token);
            // pass the token in session
            sessionStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
            // set the auth token
            setAuthToken(token);

            // decode the auth token
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            // pass the decoded token
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))

        })
        .catch(err => {
            if(err.response.data){
                console.log(err.response)
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: err.response.data
                })
            }
        })
}

export const setCurrentUser = (decoded, dispatch) => {
    return{
        type:SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload:decoded,

    }

}
```

How would i go about converting this action into a saga function/action instead ?

currently the backend throws an error,

> bad request

maybe because its not fetching the right data or something.

here is my attempt

**action.js**

```
export const userLogin = userData => dispatch => ({
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    userData
})

export const userLogInSuccess = data => ({
    type: USER_LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    data
})

export const userLogInFailure = error => ({
    type: USER_LOG_IN_FAILURE,
    error
  })

export const setCurrentUser = (decoded, dispatch) => {
    return{
        type:SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload:decoded,

    }

}
```

**saga/auth.js**

```
import api from '../api';
import { SET_CURRENT_USER, GET_ERRORS, GET_CURRENT_USER} from '../actions/types';
import {userLogInSuccess, setCurrentUser, userLogInFailure} from '../actions/authActions';
export function* userLogin(action){
    try{
        const user = yield call(api.user.loginUser, action.data);
        const token = user.token
        console.log(token);
        // pass the token in session

        sessionStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
        setAuthToken(token);
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        // pass the decoded token
        // dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))
        yield put(userLogInSuccess(user));
        yield put( setCurrentUser(decoded))
    }
    catch(error){
        yield put(userLogInFailure(error.response.data));
    }
}

export function* watchUserLogIn() {
    yield takeLatest(SET_CURRENT_USER, userLogin);
}


export default function* () {
    yield fork(watchUserLogIn);
}
```

**api**

```
import Axios from './Axios';

export default {
    user:{
        loginUser: userData => 
            Axios.post('/users/login',userData).then(res => res.data.token)
    }
};
```

**Login component**

```
.....
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {formData} = this.state;
    const {username, password} = formData;
    const creds = {
        username,
        password
    }
    this.props.userLogin(creds);


    // console.log(creds);
}
....
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    userLogin: (userData) => dispatch(userLogin(userData)),
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your payload in Network tab, if request has been called, it means action from your saga function has passed into api.